# ReferenceError navigator is not defined for FingerprintJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fingerprintjs2

I am trying to acquire browser fingerprint with the help of [fingerprintjs2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fingerprintjs2), an npm module in Javascript. But it gives me following error:-

```
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
```

Logs:
[image: Logs on terminal]

Code:

```
const Fingerprint = require('fingerprintjs2');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();

const fpInstance = new Fingerprint();
fpInstance.get((result,err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log('Error obtained',err)
    }
    else{
        console.log(result)
    } 
})
```

Comment: You may need to load `express` before `fingerprintjs2`, because it adds browser compatibility features to node.js.

Comment: I have tried doing so, but it still provides me the same error!!

Comment: Sounds like fingerprintjs2 is designed to run in browsers, it's depending on things that don't exist in node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that `fingerprintjs2` is a Javascript Library, doesn't work fine in Node.js. Luckily, a server-side version of the same has been released i.e, [**Fingerprint express middleware**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fingerprint) which is used for so called *Passive fingerprinting*.

**Installation:** `npm install express-fingerprint`

**Usage:**

```
var Fingerprint = require('express-fingerprint')

app.use(Fingerprint({
    parameters:[
        // Defaults
        Fingerprint.useragent,
        Fingerprint.acceptHeaders,
        Fingerprint.geoip,

        // Additional parameters
        function(next) {
            // ...do something...
            next(null,{
            'param1':'value1'
            })
        },
        function(next) {
            // ...do something...
            next(null,{
            'param2':'value2'
            })
        },
    ]
}))

app.get('*',function(req,res,next) {
    // Fingerprint object
    console.log(req.fingerprint)
})
```